# Warning icon remains after page layout is reset to site definition in SP Designer 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, site-definition

When I reset a page layout to its site definition by right-clicking the page layout name in SP Designer 2010, choosing Reset to Site Definition, Clicking Yes on the warning that pops up, the warning icon remains. (A backup of the customised page is created).
What is going on - has the reset worked?

Hope someone can help - I can't find anything on the web about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also have faced this issue; doing an IIS reset seemed to fix the problem.

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint.SE! While this could potentially answer the question, we [encourage more](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) than one line answers. You can edit your answer by clicking the edit link.

Answer (score 3):

This happens if you have Web Parts defined in your Page Layout. As soon as the Page Layout gets deployed, the Web Parts are being extracted out of the Page Layout and managed by the Web Parts Framework. Because the Page Layout gets modified in this process, the "unghosted" status remains.

Other explanations can be an incorrect @Page-Header or following property in the page header that SharePoint Designer creates: meta:progid="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document"

Answer (score 1):

What I have seen is that the page is not reverted back to the site definition if the icon still appears.

The only way I was able to fix this was to rename the page using the windows explorer view of the master page gallery.  I then deactivated and reactivated the feature that put the layout in the gallery in the first place.